# How do i order posts by view counts using impressionist gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Can someone please help me out with this... What i want is a sort of popular post widget which is going to be ordered by highest views. I'm using impressionist gem and i was able to add pageviews to show page. BTW, i don't understand it from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist#adding-column-to-model

Add a column to your posts table to hold the impressions count, and then you can use `order` to sort the posts by view count. `Post.order(impressions_count: :desc)`

Comment: Hey it worked after after adding the impressions count to the model.